# Search for null and values (but not for non exists) in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three documents, first: I have an empty `images` object, second: I have a null in `images.front`, and third: I have object in `images.front`.

As follows:

```
[{
  "images": {}
}, {
  "images": {
    "front": null
  }
}, { 
  "images": {
    "front": {
      "id": 1
    }
  }
}]
```

How can I search only for the documents that have `front` image (documents two and three, but not first)?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i know(i worked only till 1.7.2), document 1 and 2 will have same json structure in _source document of the elastic.As elasticsearch doesn't support null values.

So if you want to search for documents which have images , do a exists filters in the must bool filter.

[elastic null values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html)

[Exists filter in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

Comment: so you say there is nothing i can do?

Comment: try to model your data in a  different way , with array of  image objects along with the count .

Comment: what is the difference? empty array will be the same as null and not exists.. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html#CO126-1

Comment: i'm know that i can change the model, but it's dirty.. if there is no other option i will change my model :( thanks